# "this" undefined in axios catch block despite arrow functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm getting the error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

With this code:

```
class Registration extends React.Component {

  state = {...}

  submitRegistration = e => {
      let registration = {...}

      Axios.post('/registration', registration)
        .then(res => {
          console.log("Successfully sent registration data", res)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          this.setState({ showNoServerConnectionAlert: true })
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }

export default Registration;
```

The problem is that "this" can't be referenced in the catch block for some reason although I'm using arrow functions. I've tried binding "this" as well but that didn't work either. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The error message you mentioned would be a problem with your render method. Can you show us the render method?

Comment: wow, thanks that tip solved it. The problem was that I rendered a component conditionally when my "showNoServerConnectionAlert" was set to true in the catch block but that component itself was undefined. The react error message confused me a bit I think.

Comment: There's also a mismatch with the opening versus closing parentheses in your code snippet. It's really important to provide a [mcve] when asking for help.

Answer (score -3):

because "this" in the each block of code may have different means and refer to some other parent. 
for solving this problem you have to define a variable in the global scope and make it equal to this. then in the rest of the code that variable may be accessible.

```
    class Registration extends React.Component {
       state = {...}
       submitRegistration = e => {
      let registration = {...}
      var sellf = this;

      Axios.post('/registration', registration)
        .then(res => {
          console.log("Successfully sent registration data", res)
        })
        .catch(() => {
          sellf.setState({ showNoServerConnectionAlert: true })
        });
    }
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      ...
    )
  }
export default Registration;
```

Comment: No, the arrow function construct does this for you.

Comment: This won't work either because now `sellf` will be the `this` of the (still) arrow function `submitRegistration` which is still the wrong `this`.

Comment: I think this will cause an error because you cannot define a `var` inside a `class` body.